# Can not login to (graphical terminal) and stuttering

Tags: freeze, login-screen

I'm new to Linux and chose Ubuntu onto recommendation of The Odin project.
I got an issue that everything is slow and laggy (stuttering) and I tried to fix it with doing system updates. According to my guide, I should have rebooted my system to stop the stuttering.
However, as a result I got this:

```
    Jbuntu 22.04.2 LTS alan-s6o0Fa tty6
alan-9600FG logint alan
Password:
Welcome te Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/LInux 6.2.0-26-generie x86_64)

Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com

Management: https://landscape.canonical.com

Support: https://ubuntu.com/advantage

Expanded Security Naintenance for Applications is not enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.

Enable ESN Apps to receive additional future security updates.
See https://ubuntu.com/esm or run: sudo pro status

Last login: Fri Aug 4 17:45:33 CEST 2023 on tty5

alan@alan-9600FG:~$
```

Help would be appreciated, especially by someone who is a first time Linux user.
Please tell me if my formatting/writing a question was wrong. I'm as new to this website as I am to Linux.